# SpamAssassin: is there a way to get the urls that were found in blacklists?

Tags: spamassassin

Is it possible to make SpamAssassin show the urls that were found in blacklists?

Example: when rules like URIBL_JP_SURBL or URIBL_WS_SURBL matches.

I'm trying to search for a config directive that would add those urls as an extra header or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in part. The SpamAssassin report should include (only) the hostname. For example:

```
Content analysis details:   (9.2 points, 3.9 required)

 pts rule name              description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
 2.5 URIBL_DBL_SPAM         Contains a spam URL listed in the DBL blocklist
                            [URIs: canadiantabletstore.com]
 1.7 URIBL_BLACK            Contains an URL listed in the URIBL blacklist
                            [URIs: canadiantabletstore.com]
 1.6 URIBL_WS_SURBL         Contains an URL listed in the WS SURBL blocklist
                            [URIs: canadiantabletstore.com]
 1.2 URIBL_JP_SURBL         Contains an URL listed in the JP SURBL blocklist
                            [URIs: canadiantabletstore.com]
```

(Full data: [example 1](https://serverfault.com/a/638279/209449), [example 2](https://pastebin.com/CTPpTWT7))

Reports are enabled for convicted mail by default and are configured with `report_safe 1` in your `local.cf` file. To force the report (regardless of conviction) from the command line, run `spamc -R < message.eml` (to query your `spamd` server) or else `spamassassin -t < message.eml` (to run standalone).

You can configure SpamAssassin to put the whole report into a header, but that's pretty verbose (see the full data examples above). Search the man pages (notably [Mail::SpamAssassin::Conf](https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/4.0.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Conf.html)) for "report" or the `_REPORT_` template tag.